# How do I use afconvert to convert all the files in a directory from wav to caf?

Tags: command-line, audio, wav, caf, afconvert

I have a directory with about 50 wav files that I need to convert to caf, because AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID() returns an error for some of them (but not all).

Here's an example of the command I've used successfully for a single file:

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 whistle.wav whistle.caf
```

How do I do this quickly - not one-by-one for each file?

Comment: You should look at the other answers. You marked a Windows-specific answer for a Mac question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Windows, use the `%~ni` syntax.

```
for %i in (*.wav) do afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 %i %~ni.caf
```

Comment: I see, it removes the last filename extension.  Cool!

Comment: I tried to use that command but it gave mi this error:

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: That's because this particular `for` command is for the Windows command processor, not for the bash *nix shell.

Comment: Why is a Windows-specific answer marked as correct for a Mac question? It looks irrelevant to me.

Comment: "afconvert" doesn't run on windows

Answer (score 36):

Similar approach for bash: `for i in *.wav; do afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 $i ${i%.wav}.caf; done`

Answer (score 5):

found this:

```
##
## Shell script to batch convert all files in a directory to caf sound format for iPhone
## Place this shell script a directory with sound files and run it: 'sh converttocaf.sh'
## Any comments to 'support@ezone.com'
##
 
for f in *; do
    if  [ "$f" != "converttocaf.sh" ]
    then
        /usr/bin/afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 "$f"
        echo "$f converted"
    fi
done
```

Customize the afconvert options then save it as a text file called 'converttocaf.sh', place it in the directory of files you want to convert and run it from Terminal.

It works with files with spaces in their names.

Comment: combined it with a bit of syntax from Randall's answer and my own conversion settings and it worked great!  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

For the people who are using OSX and are a bit afraid of Terminal scripts I created a little application with Automator, this application converts the files you select.

Download [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/135074/convert-to-caff.zip)

Comment: I just updated the link, it's now available at: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/135074/convert-to-caff.zip

Answer (score 5):

```
for file in *.wav; do afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 "$file"; done
```

Hit the Return key directly after `done`.

Simple :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with filenames that contain spaces on Linux, try the following code:

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS 
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b"); for i in *.wav; do afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 $i ${i%.wav}.caf; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Python script on OSX.  Default data format of the `.caf` is `ima4`.  Default directory is `'.'`

Make a file called `wav2caf.py`, put it in your path, make it executable, fill it with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import os
import argparse
import glob

def main():
    # handle command line args
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A program that converts .wav to .caf files.', formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_help = True
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--folder', dest='folder', type=str, default='.', help='folder of files to convert')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--data', dest='data', type=str, default='ima4', help='data format of .caf')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # process files in folder
    os.chdir(args.folder)
    for filename in glob.glob("*.wav"):
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        command = 'afconvert -f caff -d ' + args.data + ' ' + filename + ' ' + name + '.caf'
        os.system(command)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Converts all .wav to .caf in current directory:

```
wav2caf.py
```

Converts all .wav to .caf in specified directory:

```
wav2caf.py -f Desktop/wavs/
```

Converts all .wav to .caf with data type 'aac ':

```
wav2caf.py -d 'aac '
```