# convert apple recording formats to WAV format

Tags: iphone, wav, audioformat

How to convert Apple recording formats to WAV format ?
As said in Audio Queue Service Programming Guide, the apple recording formats are

- Apple Lossless
- iLBC
- IMA/ ADPCM
- u-Law and a-Law

So if i record an audio in any of these formats, how to convert it into WAV format?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `afconvert` which is Apple's utility, or any number of quality sound programs out there can do this as well.

afconvert example: [How do I use afconvert to convert all the files in a directory from wav to caf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271354/how-do-i-use-afconvert-to-convert-all-the-files-in-a-directory-from-wav-to-caf)

audacity: http://audacity.sourceforge.net/